# How do I display a nested JSON structure as HTML, using PHP?

Tags: php, json

Given the following JSON structure thats stored in a file:

```
{
  "RETS": {
    "COUNT": {
      "_Records": "500"
    },
    "RED": {
      "REP": {
        "ResiProp": [{
          "all": {
            "Address": "xyz lane hy1",
            "Directions": "",
            "K": "1",
            "Remarks": "item1; item 2;item 3",
            "IdxUpdtedDt": "2019-07-05 10:19:49.0",
            "H": "Air"
          }
        }]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

How do I read the data, parse it, and convert it to HTML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you want to use json_decode()
http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Presumably you want to start with storing the json above in a string variable. `json_decode()` converts a valid json string to an object or an array. Try something like this.

```
$jsonStr = '{"a": 100, "b": 200, "c": "hello world"}';
$jsonObj = json_decode($jsonStr);  

echo $jsonObj->c; //prints "hello world"
```

An example with some nesting

```
$jsonStr = '{
  "a": {
    "name": "joe", "age": 25
  },

  "b": 999,

  "c": ["apple","orange","pear"]
}';

$jsonObj = json_decode($jsonStr);

echo "<br/>" . $jsonObj->a->name; //joe
echo "<br/>" . $jsonObj->c[2]; //pear
```

---

In order to echo just one, string property from your original json data. And assuming that the data you posted in your original question is in a file called data.json (in the same folder as the script). This is how you echo the "Address" property.

```
<?php

//Ensures errors are printed out
error_reporting(-1);

//Read the contents of data.json into a variable
$jsonStr = file_get_contents('data.json');

//Convert the string to an object in memory using the json parser
$jsonObj = json_decode($jsonStr);

//Do something with the object
echo $jsonObj->RETS->RED->REP->ResiProp[0]->all->Address;

?>
```

Comment: im not sure using it right way if you can show me how i can do will be appreciated its gives out array in output

Comment: No worries I'll edit the answer

Comment: RETS": {
    "COUNT": {
      "_Records": "500"
    },
    "RED": {
      "REP": {
        "ResiProp":  how do i get that level from rets to resiprop if i have that directly from website

Comment: `$jsonObj->RETS->RED->REP->ResiProp[0]->all->Address; //xyz lane hy1`

Comment: tried not working above $jsonObj->RETS->RED->REP->ResiProp[0]->all->Address;

Comment: How are you reading the json data into a string? You said it was in a file. Are you using something like `file_get_contents()`? Maybe post the code you have tried so far in your original question.

Comment: <?php

$jsonStr = '{
 "RETS": {
  "COUNT": {
   "_Records": "700",
  },
  "RED": {
   "REP": {
    "ResiProp": [
     {
      "all": {
            "Address": "xyz lane hy1",
            "Directions": "",
            "K": "1",
            "Remarks": "item1; item 2;item 3",
            "IdxUpdtedDt": "2019-07-05 10:19:49.0",
            "H": "Air"
          }
        }]
      }
    }
  }
}';
$jsonObj = json_decode($jsonStr);  

echo "<br/>" . $jsonObj->RETS->COUNT->RED>REP->ResiProp[0];

?>

Comment: however i want that to be both ways by files and online im really confused...how it will work

Comment: OK there are a few problems. 1. You have a syntax error. You've missed a `-` where it says `->RED>REP`. It should be `->RED->REP`. 2. You have included `COUNT` in the reference and it is not in the path that you want (it isn't a parent of the value you want which is `ResiProp`). 3. The json data you've just provided is invalid. The version in your original question is fine. 4. You are trying to echo an object which you cannot do. In my example I was echoing a string but ResiProp[0] is an object.

Comment: <?php
jsonStr='{
  "RETS": {
    "COUNT": {
      "_Records": "500"
    },
    "RED": {
      "REP": {
        "ResiProp": [{
          "all": {
            "Address": "xyz lane hy1",
            "Directions": "",
            "K": "1",
            "Remarks": "item1; item 2;item 3",
            "IdxUpdtedDt": "2019-07-05 10:19:49.0",
            "H": "Air"
          }
        }]
      }
    }
  }
}';




$jsonObj = json_decode($jsonStr); 

echo "<br/>" . $jsonObj->RETS->RED->REP->ResiProp[0]->all; ?>

Comment: above one is not good what am i doing wrong

Comment: You need to be more careful with syntax. You're missing a $ symbol at the very beginning. And... `->all` is an object and you cannot echo an object as I've already said. What do you actually want to do? It doesn't sound like you're getting any error messages. Put `error_reporting(-1);` at the beginning of your script.

Comment: I've amended the answer again and it sounds like you want to be able to store the json in a separate file so I've shown how to do that too. However what you want to do with the data at the end will dictate how you handle $jsonObj. I've just shown one example (to echo the Address property)

Comment: jsonStr='{
  "RETS": {
    "COUNT": {
      "_Records": "500"
    },
    "RED": {
      "REP": {
        "ResiProp": [{
          "all": {
            "Address": "xyz lane hy1",
            "Directions": "",
            "K": "1",
            "Remarks": "item1; item 2;item 3",
            "IdxUpdtedDt": "2019-07-05 10:19:49.0",
            "H": "Air"
          }
        }]
      }
    }
  }
}';

Comment: thanks so much can i ask you if i had other issues....also same can be done using online if this keep online in my server?

Comment: if i have n number of nesting will i able to search by using any query in jason?